# RCP Export extension point schema reference document

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

My goal is to export the extension point schema reference document. In the schema editor there is a huge section to enter the documentation and I know I can *preview* it using the Preview Reference Document button in the top right corner, but thats just temporary

Basically I want to export all schema files that exist within the workspace (which consists of several projects) so it looks something like [this](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html)

There must be a way to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this in the Preferences in the 'Plug-in Development > Compilers' page.

On the 'Schemas' tab check the 'Generate reference documentation from schemas' option and set a location for the output.

This uses the 'Extension Point Schema Builder' builder which should be in the builders list for each project using a schema (this should be the default for plug-in projects).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the answer!